# Quelle construction serait à préférer dans « La critique est aisée pour qui/quand on vit dans l’opulence plutôt que dans l’indigence »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, constructions, reformulation

> La critique est aisée (Ou c’est facile à dire) pour qui vit dans l’opulence plutôt que dans l’indigence.

> La critique est aisée (Ou c’est facile à dire) quand on vit dans l’opulence plutôt que dans l’indigence.

À votre avis, quelle construction serait préférable, celle avec la préposition « pour » ou celle avec la conjonction « quand »? N’hésitez pas à repenser la phrase dans vos propres mots, de préférence en préservant les termes « opulence » et « indigence », si jamais vous trouvez que les deux versions présentées sont boiteuses ou si vous pensez simplement qu’il en serait mieux ainsi, à en juger par votre intuition d’ordre esthétique.

Comment: "pour celui qui vit dans etc.", je dirais. Le fait d'utiliser les deux mots est ce qui fait le charme de la phrase. Tout reécrire comme ça ne me semble pas justifié.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Je dirais que la préposition « pour » est traditionnellement utilisée dans ce type d'énonciation,  c'est celle qu'on trouvera dans la langue littéraire ; « quand on » appartient à la langue ordinaire.

*Quelques exemples tirés de la littérature*

- Tout est imprévu pour qui ne s'occupe de rien
- je ne sais pas l'art d'être clair pour qui ne veut pas être attentif
- De quelle importance , nous dira-t-on, peut être le suffrage de l'oreille pour qui ne vient pas amuser un auditoire oisif avec une éloquence vaine
- proprement incompréhensible pour qui ne maîtrisait que la langue contemporaine
- Or, le droit, comme les autres professions, possède son propre langage, qui n'est pas toujours facilement compréhensible pour qui ne l'a pas appris et ne le pratique pas

Une formulation alternative sans essayer de considérer une nuance qui porte sur l'ampleur relative de l'opulence, et donc en supprimant « plutôt que dans l'indigence », que je ne trouve pas très précis de toute façon, donnerait à l'énoncé un caractère absolu qui, je pense, n'enlèverait rien à sa valeur, ou peu, et tendrait par sa concision à produire une assertion qui s'apparente à la maxime.

- La critique est aisée  pour qui vit dans l’opulence.

Telle qu'écrite initialement, il me semble que l'on ne sait pas très bien s'il s'agit de pencher plutôt du coté de l'opulence, c'est à dire d'être au moins un peu opulent, ou s'il s'agit de connaitre à la fois l'opulence et une condition qui ne l'est plus, en préférant cette première. J'ai même l'impression que cette utilisation de « plutôt » relève de l'anglicisme.